# Using e.PreventDefault stops the returned response loading in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I upload a file via a form to the webserver but when completed the response is somehow not being displayed, even though if I check the developer status tools (in Chrome/Firefox) it is getting returned.

Originally I was just using a form & post but have since switched to trying to provide a JS solutuion as the files are large & I want to display upload progress & time expected to complete

```
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    if (isAdvancedUpload) {
        let formData = new FormData(document.forms.upload);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress);
        xhr.open('POST', '/load', true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

In all browsers this uploads the file but response is never displayed (even though in developer / network / response the full HTML is returned)

If I do **NOT** use e.preventDefault();  it works as expected but only in Chrome (not Safari & Firefox)

This is the console stack trace at the end (My script ends with a 302 redirect and a GET request on original script -- required behaviour)

```
XHR GET https://************.com/load  [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 42ms]

<anonymous> https://***************.com/js/uploader.js:86:8 
dispatch https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:42571
add/v.handle https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:40572
```

Any pointers please?

Comment: I don't exactly understand why you need `e.preventDefault()`, but you can try moving it at the end of your function. Is your element bound to other events somewhere else in your code?

Comment: What exactly does `updateProgress` do?  Since you are performing an ajax request, the page is not going to show results, unless you dynamically change the page to include them.

Comment: ```e.preventDefault()``` does not allow ```updateProgress``` to function in Firefox ???

Comment: ```updateProgress``` is my function to calculate and display "progress"

Comment: So where is your logic that handles the response of the ajax call to modify the page with the results?

Comment: You're not setting up a `readystatechange` or `success` event handler, so there's no place to capture the returned value and work with it.

Comment: So that's your problem, ya?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio The location of `e.preventDefault()` shouldn't make any difference. It affects what happens after the function returns.

Comment: Please **[read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)** on how to set up a proper AJAX request.

Comment: If you remove `e.preventDefault()`, the form should be submitted normally in addition to the AJAX request, so the page should reload. I don't see how that could allow this to work as expected.

Comment: I don't think anyone was suggesting it be removed.  Only comment I see is to move it, which doesn't address the real issue.

Comment: So how do I get the server response delivered to actually reload the page? (with the content it delivers)

Comment: I have answered that for you twice already. Please read the link I've shared. You need to set up a `readystatechanged` or `success` event callback.